# When I use AnalogueWrite the voltage doesn't vary properly

Tags: voltage, analogwrite

I have a project where I want to control a pump, I use an Arduino, connected to a driver L298N and I will connect the pin 5, 6, 7 of the arduino to the pin IN2, IN1, ENA of the driver respectively and the motor will be connected to the output

My materiel :

- Arduino Uno R3
- Multimeter
- Arduino IDE 2.1.1

The issue :
When I use the function analogWrite the voltage vary only between two value (0v or 5.5v).
The pin used was the Digital pin n°7, noted in the code 7.

The code :

```cpp
#define PUMP_DIR_1 5
#define PUMP_DIR_2 6
#define PUMP_PWM 7
#define INVERTED 0

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PUMP_PWM, OUTPUT);
}

void set_pump_speed(int speed){
  Serial.print("Set speed ");
  Serial.print(speed);
  Serial.print("\r\n");
  analogWrite(PUMP_PWM, speed);
}

void loop() {
  set_pump_speed(255);
  delay(3000);
  set_pump_speed(0);
  delay(3000);
  set_pump_speed(125);
  delay(3000);
}
```

As output I obtained :

> 00:32:17.184 -> Set speed 0
> 00:32:20.175 -> Set speed 125
> 00:32:23.178 -> Set speed 255
> 00:32:26.182 -> Set speed 0
> 00:32:29.197 -> Set speed 125
> 00:32:32.201 -> Set speed 255

From the mutlimeter I obtained :

> 0v when speed = 0
> 0v when speed = 125
> 5.5v when speed = 255

The arduino is not wired to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin 7 isn't a PWM pin. Use, say, pin 6 and you will get correct results. The PWM pins are marked with a "~" on the board.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I feel stupid, because it is not the first time I use PWM on Arduino and I never took this in consideration.

Comment: @Nept0 Don't worry! It must have worked last time by chance, now you know why. :)